# Customized SharePoint online library with Power Apps not saving

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps-forms

I have customized my SharePoint online document library with Power Apps so users can have a better view when they edit the records. It has no formula or complex rule. I added a new screen and display form and move half of the columns into the new form. I created two buttons for the navigation so users can navigate between the forms.
The problem is users can use SharePoint save button to save the form that was created by default. but when the update the new form and try to save the it, nothing happens.

Kind Regards [image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to save and publish the customized form into SharePoint.

[image]

Second, go to List settings -> Form Settings -> Choose Use a custom form created in PowerApps (requires new list experience).

Answer (score 0):

OnSave = NewForm(SharePointForm); NewForm(SharePointForm1);